# Video is not playing in android phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, video, cordova

The video is playing well in web browser.

But it's not working in android phonegap application.it's showing white color background alone.it's well working with fullscreen.

[image: Please check the video]

I have using below code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/video.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <body>
     <video class="video" poster="images/playlink.jpg" controls="" width="768" height="432" preload="none">
       <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
     </video>
     </body>
    </html>
```